# Finding $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(\frac{x+\ln x}{ x-\ln x})^{\frac{x}{\ln x}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(\frac{x+\ln x}{ x-\ln x})^{\frac{x}{\ln x}}$. I tried using l'Hospital rule with the continuity of $e$ function. Also tried using Taylor expansion with no success. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: I used l'Hospital rule 2 times and it worked.

Comment: Whith ${{xln ({x+lnx\over x-lnx})}\over ln x}$?

Comment: I had $\frac{lnx}{x}$ in denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{x+\log x}{x-\log x}\right)^{\frac x{\log x}}
=&\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{2\log x}{x-\log x}\right)^{\frac x{\log x}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{\frac{x}{\log x}-1}\right)^{\frac x{\log x}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{\frac{x}{\log x}-1}\right)^{\frac x{\log x}-1}\left(1+\frac{2}{\frac{x}{\log x}-1}\right)\\
=&e^2
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! 
I started that way and wouldn't believe it can work and stopped.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2):

With $t=\frac{x}{\ln x}$ your limit can be written
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty} \Bigl(\frac{1+1/t}{1-1/t}\Bigr)^t.
$$
If you know that
$$
e=\lim_{t\to+\infty}(1+1/t)^t
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{e}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}(1-1/t)^t
$$
then you are essentially done.

Answer (score 1):

Justify the following using

$$f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty\implies \left(1+\frac a{f(x)}\right)^{f(x)}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e^a:$$

$$\left(\frac{x+\log x}{x-\log x}\right)^{x/\log x}=\left(1+\frac2{\frac x{\log x}-1}\right)^{\frac x{\log x}-1}\cdot\left(1+\frac2{\frac x{\log x}-1}\right)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e^2\cdot1=e^2$$